# How to access values from multi dimension array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to access the value. If I give `{Movie.Score}`, the score will print. In,

```
[{"score":0.70159364,"show":{"id":34653,"url":"https://www.tvmaze.com/shows/34653/all-american","name":"All American","type":"Scripted","language":"English",
```

I want to print names. I am using `{movie.name}` and `{movie.score.name}`, but it's not printing.

Answer (score -1):

Assumming that your array looks like this, you have to first tell your code which element in your array you want to access to so you write `movie[index].show.name`

If `movie` is your array then you have to acces each element by it's index.

and also `movie.score.name` won't work becuz `name` is not a property inside the `score` key

```js
const movie = [{
    "score": 0.70159364,
    "show": {
      "id": 34653,
      "url": "https://www.tvmaze.com/shows/34653/all-american",
      "name": "All American",
      "type": "Scripted",
      "language": "English"
    }
}];

console.log(movie[0].show.name)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can access by     console.log('movie name ',  this.item[0]['show']['name']);

Demo below.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ja2m6n?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: you aware that you `console.log('movie name ', this.item[0]['name']);` returns undefined even in the link you provided right?